# what is property of connectionString to connect SQL database to my MVC 5 web-app?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning MVC 5 and try to programming a web application. I'm following a toturial, but the problem is I can't fit the ConnectionString with may dataBase which is SQL Server.

This is a part of my web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MovieDBContext"
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf; Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I think this is wrong beacuse it said that the source can not be found when I run the codes.
I have to know the whole elements of connectionString tag and what they mean.

Thanks everybody

Comment: `Source can not be found` - can you show the message details here? Ensure that Windows authentication enabled and the MDF file exists in `App_Data` folder of your project.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2556.0

Comment: That was the whole error message and in my app_Data is empty

Comment: HTTP 404... seems that a redirect or GET method can't find certain requested page in URL. Which URL you want to access (please include [mcve])? If it's a DB error then the message should be like  'unable to establish connection with SQL Server'.

Comment: I hope that `|DataDirectory|` is replaced by the actual directory in your real code ?